# Rails serializer isn't called on Mongoid embedded class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, active-model-serializers

I have two mongoid models, let's call them `Model` and `ModelChild`. This is relation in `Model`:

```
embeds_many :readings, class_name: 'ModelChild', inverse_of: :model
```

And this is relation in `model_child`:

```
embedded_in :model, class_name: 'Model', inverse_of: :readings
```

The problem is that `ModelSerializer` is called, but `ModelChildSerializer` isn't. Am I doing something wrong or is this by design? If it's by design, how can I make it call `ModelChildSerializer`.

EDIT:

Controller's rendering call:

```
render json: obj, serializer: ObjSerializer
```

And code in `ObjSerializer`:

```
  def attributes
    data = super
    data[:data] = ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(data[:data])
    data
  end
```

Comment: could you show the controller code to render the request that it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveModel Serialization is not supported for embedded documents...if you want a workaround check this out http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/extend-ds-activemodelserializer-support-for-embedded-objects-belongsto-relationship-using-has-one/3392

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find any time to try it out yet. I'll try it as soon as I clear my high priority tasks ;)